# Dropdown Item style

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi i want to First Item in Drop down in Bold font how can i do that

in first item "select" text i have in Drop down
any buddy tell me

Comment: 11 questions without any accept or upvote...

Answer (score 2):

```
li:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: on server side how can i do and above code which u gave me how can and where right

Comment: Yep, note that for this to work in IE, you need to specify a doc type so it's not in Quirks mode: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp

Comment: This is CSS so you need to add this riule to your stylesheet. And note the comment by @Zhaph-Ben Duguid

Comment: and if i want to do same thing in second  row then can i write second instead of li:first-child{  ??

Answer (score 0):

At an absolute push, you could access the Attributes collection of the list item as you add it, and apply a class or style directly to it:

```
ListItem select = new ListItem();
select.Text = "select";
select.Value = string.Empty;
select.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight: bold;");
```

But I'd really recommend taking [Vincent's route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427437/dropdown-item-style/1427465#1427465), and do it through CSS - if needs be, you can add a class declaration in there as well, and add the class to the Drop-down.